# How to use Data Studio bindings in a Vega chart code table?

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio, vega-lite, vega, data-studio-custom-visuals

I would like to implement an example of RoseWid chart in Data Studio using the Vega community visualization, using [this](https://observablehq.com/@stanisouce/vega-wind-rose-or-radial-stacked-bar-chart-in-progress) great code from Stan Nowak. Once adapted for the Vega plugin, it looks like this:

```
    {"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"g": "1", "c": 0, "r": 11},
        {"g": 1, "c": 1, "r": 22},
        {"g": 1, "c": 2, "r": 13},
        {"g": 2, "c": 0, "r": 24},
        {"g": 2, "c": 1, "r": 35},
        {"g": 2, "c": 2, "r": 36},
        {"g": 3, "c": 0, "r": 42},
        {"g": 3, "c": 1, "r": 32},
        {"g": 3, "c": 2, "r": "32"},
        {"g": 4, "c": 0, "r": 6},
        {"g": 4, "c": 1, "r": 27},
        {"g": 4, "c": 2, "r": 16},
        {"g": 5, "c": 0, "r": 52},
        {"g": 5, "c": 1, "r": 79},
        {"g": 5, "c": 2, "r": 38},
        {"g": 6, "c": 0, "r": 19},
        {"g": 6, "c": 1, "r": 83},
        {"g": 6, "c": 2, "r": 3}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "angles",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "aggregate", "groupby": ["g"]},
        {"type": "pie"}
      ]
    },{
      "name": "stack",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stack", "groupby": ["g"], "sortby": ["c"], "field": "r"},
        {"type": "lookup", "from": "angles", "key": "g", "fields": ["g"], "as": ["obj"]}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "stack", "field": "c"},
      "range": {"scheme": "redyellowgreen"}
    },
    {
      "name": "r",
      "type": "sqrt",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y"},
      "range": [20, 200]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "stack"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"field": {"group": "width"}, "mult": 0.5},
          "y": {"field": {"group": "height"}, "mult": 0.5},
          "startAngle": {"data": "table", "field": "obj.startAngle"},
          "endAngle": {"data": "table", "field": "obj.endAngle"},
          "innerRadius": {"field": "y0"},
          "outerRadius": {"field": "y1"},
          "stroke": {"value": "black"}
        },
        "update": {"fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}},
        "hover": {"fill": {"value": "red"}}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

The dataset has beed arranged in datastudio to have the same structure as the provided sample table ( with 3 columns with the same structure as the inline table). However I´m stuck on how to replace the table with the Data Studio bindings (namely, `$dimension0`, `$dimension1` and `$metric0`)¨.

So far I tried:

```
 "data": [
        {
          "name": "table",
          "values": ["$dimension0","$dimension1","$metric0"],
          "as": ["g","c","r"]
},
....
```

and some variations on this, all to no result. The visualization keeps blank and there´s little information on what is failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* : Here's a **[google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KLTwA9M92ltb-P8FsH9Drl4SASyBrkLvB2ke_B-x8k/edit?usp=sharing)** that is reproducing the same structure as the table in the inline code, which would be used as data for the Data Studio, and you can find an example of the working visualization & attempts to solve **[here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7fec95cb-aea1-4101-833a-0d85d4f935c0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same issue and managed to solve this after so many trial-and-errors.

To bind with data studio, you have to name your data as
`"default"` and you can simply rename the fields by transforming with `"type" : "project"` in Vega.

```
 "data": [
        {
          "name": "default",
          "transform" : [{ "type" : "project",
                          "fields" : ["$dimension0","$dimension1","$metric0"],
                          "as": ["g","c","r"]}
          ]
},
....
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in your example Vega source: *stack* transform does not have *"sortby"*. Instead, specify *"sort"*:

```
   "sort": { "field": ["c"],
              "order": ["ascending"]
    },
```

[View example in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aACwAGNTPg0yWVRpkKkmFKgDaocUgRw0IE0wA2tmcSSOGcCGgsgydgEZpECg0TRAAJzQAgIBfKVB-VACZUOSZKNQAJiz4xOjUtCyM6IBmPL8iwtRwzKyVCqTikILItFKBRqqW7JLUUoA2Lv7q2tVchMqRnpS2-on86bTmzJBSrJBhlVG%20ocmk7Zm%20rIB2LeqV6L3FgR25gQWp26O5k4BOYeflvtKADmGBndMgEPvs0ICXplfuUwagId85uUALoVKw2OxIcRkZzeGRiBgRKC2dAOZzBTARTEQABmbAiCB8oEwAE8cMSQEgyGQInxMC4-BE2AwcExmT5KijJiy2XYcDRbLFJZZrOyICYoABrYL4wns0n8ilU2n0xn2Vmq9VamTcoUisXmCV4umYNCganyxwKcWhJEyOkKOCZMwc6BwcQKGhYkCSkDuuCeuxRCrS9mONhsDXC4LUwUM9CY7FeYIauD2yoyOOe7wO-y%20kPithMYTRxWKvFQdxF8zK9HoKBsNNRGQpuyOSNwJBDkAKNjISOu6fGUwgNVITXZj1evubDIF4mgLiIdk8hTM%20Np2TcuBhzaolWJ8nmuwQACOERdhlnSHnqFARhMdj6hu8ZbiAYrxJEe4%20FkmgwWoKJ1sgEQatWvgjvmhLZrmC7-suq7rhBYb9gGC5hnymSgAAHgulZbokgpZug8hKDAO4gAgDCOC6NSUJ0Mj2m6m4LjajEYHAOh6BBHFcWEvEQau74AIJYmSv6LgBJJIE4-K0XYjbCJQCmYMphZsWGCgmapf5LoBWlkhWQnoPplDmZZCoyJG4iBgASkgEYMNWgkgXYzJqGxQrkb5-mBbGjlgUE8kUhm%204gG4Hjsk4a5arEEHCv%20KXuo4jgLtAnZ2P2g7AQm245VobCkBRsVFQuaWeImcBejlOV1v24jukkwA5UAA)

See Vega documentation for *[stack](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/stack/)* and *[compare](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/types/#Compare)*:

For **Google Data Studio**, I have no experience using it
but at the "[Visualizations](https://datastudio.google.com/visualization)" web page, there are examples of using Vega in Data Studio:
["Data Studio Vega Viz" by Jerry Chen](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/88379d94-19e1-4403-ae92-d279dcb2cbf5/page/Vuq9)

Based on his examples, "$dimension0","$dimension1" and "$metric0" can be used directly as Vega data fields.

Your question is how to use the Vega source that already has field names "g", "c" and "r". One way is to globally replace all "g", "c" and "r" with "$dimension0","$dimension1" and "$metric0" as shown in Jerry Chen's examples.

An alternative approach is to create formula fields "g", "c" and "r" as substitutes for "$dimension0","$dimension1" and "$metric0" as shown below. If this works then it is a general solution for converting any existing Vega spec to Google Data Studio and also for retaining meaningful field names in the Vega spec.

```
   "data": [
      { "name": "table",
        
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "as": "g",
            "expr": "datum['$dimension0']"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "as": "c",
            "expr": "datum['$dimension1']"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "as": "r",
            "expr": "datum['$metric0']"
          }
        ]
    },
  
      {
          "name": "angles",
          "source": "table",
          "transform": [
            {"type": "aggregate", "groupby": ["g"]},
            {"type": "pie"}
          ]
        }
    ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the proposed transformation does not work on Data Studio, I´ve added an editable example here [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7fec95cb-aea1-4101-833a-0d85d4f935c0) including the original working chart and a couple attempts to solving.

Comment: Your "attempt #1" shows Vega transform using "calculate". This syntax is for Vega-Lite and does not work in Vega. Please try again using the Vega code exactly as shown in Answer above, including all quotes (use copy and paste) i.e., {
            "type": "formula",
            "as": "g",
            "expr": "datum['$dimension0']"
          },

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, you code is documented on the DataStudio as Attempt#2 with exactly the same code as above (copy / paste), and still produces a blank chart. It appears this solution is not compatible at all with DataStudio bindings, as I have already tried other examples with this initial transformation with the same result ( no displayed chart at all and no error messages). You can check additional content on page 2-3 for this effect.